# How to check whether an object contains a value with TypeScript generics?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've been trying to create a way of checking whether a value provided from the database satisfies being a part of an enum. I first wanted to provide just a generic TypeGuard, then I decided it would also be nice to provide a function to not only check the value against the enum, but also provide some handling for both cases. However, TypeScript apparently doesn't allow you to provide  in the generics declaration, so I just decided to check against an object like so , which would be even more abstract, which I'd say is a welcome feature.

```
typeGuard<E extends Object>(value: string): value is E {
  return Object.values(E).includes(value);
}
```

then it understandably doesn't work, since I can't just pass E to Object.values(), since it isn't an object, but only a type. One way would be to pass the object as another argument, however, that feels kind of bulky to me, since I'm not going to be using the object any other way. Same problem persists for only wanting to use it as a function, not a type guard.

```
typeGuard<E extends Object>(values: string): boolean {
  return Object.keys(E).includes()
}
```

TL;DR - is there a way to check whether a given value is a value representing in an object just by checking the TYPE of an object and not the object itself?

Answer (score 1):

Well, NO, because typescript compilers pass NO type information into runtime.

There are ways to pass static types into runtime (using transformers), but
I doubt that will work with passing the type into generic *call*

---

The recommended way to check if the object matches whatever (deep) type properly would be using Zod, or a newer https://arktype.io/ . They have quite a bit of boilerplate (esp. Zod), but allows to ensure that objects are proper ones
ArkType has more somple boilerplate and allows to easily infer TS typedefs from validator defs, so I recommend cheching that